# How compare date and current date in Silvrerstripe template?

Tags: silverstripe

In Silverstripe template I need to compare variable $date_ok with current date like this  :  if($date_ok < date("j, n, Y") {...};

```
<% loop $IzdMat %>
<tr>
      <td>$num</td>
      <td>$sert_otip </strong> <br>Valid from $date_start  till  
$date_ok</td> 
      <% if $date_ok < ****** %>
         ..............
       <% end_if %> 
.......
```

What I have to write insted of ****** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method to the DataObject rather than trying to do complicated logic in the templates. This is assuming that `date_ok` is a date field defined in the `$db` array.

```
class IzdMat extends DataObject {

  public function IsDateOk() {
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    return (strtotime($today) < strtotime($this->date_ok));
  }
}
```

Then in your template.

```
<% loop $IzdMat %>
  <tr>
      <td>$num</td>
      <td>$sert_otip </strong> <br>Valid from $date_start  till  
$date_ok</td> 
      <% if $IsDateOk  %>
         ..............
      <% end_if %> 
  </tr>
<% end_loop %>
```